# Do you understand the problem on this POST request with lambda function?

Tags: angular, post, httprequest, netlify, faunadb

I use netlify lambda functions for CRUD operations on my project but i have an error on the POST operation

I use angular front, netlify functions and faunaDB

my lambda:

```
/* code from functions/todos-create.js */
import faunadb from 'faunadb' /* Import faunaDB sdk */

/* configure faunaDB Client with our secret */
const q = faunadb.query
const client = new faunadb.Client({
  secret: process.env.FAUNADB_SECRET
})

/* export our lambda function as named "handler" export */
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  /* parse the string body into a useable JS object */
  console.log('<<<<<<<<<' + "      " + event.body + "       " + '>>>>>>>>>')
  const eventBody = JSON.stringify(event.body)
  const data = JSON.parse(eventBody)
  console.log("Function `todo-create` invoked", data)
  const todoItem = {
    data: data
  }
  /* construct the fauna query */
  return client.query(q.Create(q.Ref("classes/todos"), todoItem))
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("success", response)
    /* Success! return the response with statusCode 200 */
    return callback(null, {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(response)
    })
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("error", error)
    /* Error! return the error with statusCode 400 */
    return callback(null, {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify(error)
    })
  })
}
```

a piece of my component:

```
public myTodo = { title: 'What I had for breakfast ..',
                    completed: true };


onSubmit() {
    this.missionService.createTodo(this.myTodo).then((response) => {
      console.log('console log of missionService.createTodo ---->');
      console.log(this.myTodo);
      console.log('API response', response);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('API error', error);
    });
  }
```

my service:

```
  createTodo(data) {
    console.log('console log of createTodo ---->');
    console.log(data);
    return fetch('/.netlify/functions/todos-create', {
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      method: 'POST'
    }).then(response => {
      return response.json();
    });
  }
```

And finnaly the execution error....

```
Request from ::ffff:127.0.0.1: POST /todos-create
[BACK] [LAMBDA] <<<<<<<<<      {"title":"What I had for breakfast ..","completed":true}       >>>>>>>>>
[BACK] [LAMBDA] Function `todo-create` invoked {"title":"What I had for breakfast ..","completed":true}
[BACK] [LAMBDA] error { [BadRequest: validation failed]
[BACK] [LAMBDA]   name: 'BadRequest',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]   message: 'validation failed',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]   requestResult:
[BACK] [LAMBDA]    RequestResult {
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      client:
[BACK] [LAMBDA]       Client {
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         _baseUrl: 'https://db.fauna.com:443',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         _timeout: 60000,
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         _secret: '******************'
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         _observer: null,
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         _lastSeen: 1559144535321508 },
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      method: 'POST',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      path: '',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      query: null,
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      requestRaw: undefined,
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      requestContent: Expr { raw: [Object] },
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      responseRaw:
[BACK] [LAMBDA]       '{"errors":[{"position":[],"code":"validation failed","description":"Instance data is not valid.","failures":[{"field":["data"],"code":"invalid type","description":"Invalid type String, expected type Map."}]}]}',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      responseContent: { errors: [Array] },
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      statusCode: 400,
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      responseHeaders:
[BACK] [LAMBDA]       { 'content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         date: 'Wed, 29 May 2019 15:42:15 GMT',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-bus-bytes-in': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-bus-bytes-out': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-bus-messages-in': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-bus-messages-out': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-faunadb-build': '2.6.4.rc4-3fa8865',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-faunadb-host': 'ec2-35-173-239-41.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-points-network-out': '0.0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-points-storage-read': '0.0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-points-storage-write': '0.0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-points-total': '0.0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-query-bytes-in': '129',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-query-bytes-out': '209',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-query-time': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-read-ops': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-storage-bytes-read': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-storage-bytes-write': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-storage-ops-delete': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-storage-ops-read': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-storage-ops-write': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-txn-delay': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-txn-retries': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-txn-time': '1559144535321508',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-write-ops': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'content-length': '209',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         connection: 'Close' },
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      startTime: 1559144535024,
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      endTime: 1559144535439 } }
[BACK] [LAMBDA] Response with status 400 in 417 ms.
[BACK] [LAMBDA] (node:10193) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at callback (/home/mathieu/Bureau/acrabadabra/Acrabadabra/node_modules/netlify-lambda/lib/serve.js:35:42)
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at /home/mathieu/Bureau/acrabadabra/Acrabadabra/node_modules/netlify-lambda/lib/serve.js:67:7
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at tryCatch (/home/mathieu/Bureau/acrabadabra/Acrabadabra/functions/todos-create.js:1803:12)
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at invokeCallback (/home/mathieu/Bureau/acrabadabra/Acrabadabra/functions/todos-create.js:1818:13)
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at publish (/home/mathieu/Bureau/acrabadabra/Acrabadabra/functions/todos-create.js:1792:7)
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at flush (/home/mathieu/Bureau/acrabadabra/Acrabadabra/functions/todos-create.js:1522:5)
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
[BACK] [LAMBDA] (node:10193) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
```

GET request is functional, i tried it.
Do you have any idea of the problem please ?

Comment: Based on this description ("Invalid type String, expected type Map") in your error , you may remove the stringify from your fetch body

Answer (score 1):

My solution, add a second JSON parse in parameter variable of the request:

```
const todoItem = {
    data: JSON.parse(data)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the stringify change nothing, I added console logs in lambda function for more details:

```
/* code from functions/todos-create.js */
import faunadb from 'faunadb' /* Import faunaDB sdk */

/* configure faunaDB Client with our secret */
const q = faunadb.query
const client = new faunadb.Client({
  secret: process.env.FAUNADB_SECRET
})

/* export our lambda function as named "handler" export */
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  /* parse the string body into a useable JS object */
  console.log('<<<<<<<<<' + "      " + event.body + "       " + '>>>>>>>>>')
  const eventBody = JSON.stringify(event.body)
  console.log('<<<<<<<<<' + "      " + eventBody + "       " + '>>>>>>>>>')
  const data = JSON.parse(eventBody)
  console.log('<<<<<<<<<' + "      " + data + "       " + '>>>>>>>>>')
  console.log("Function `todo-create` invoked", data)
  const todoItem = {
    data: data
  }
  // {"title":"What I had for breakfast ..","completed":true}
  console.log('<<<<<<<<<' + "      " + todoItem + "       " + '>>>>>>>>>')
  /* construct the fauna query */
  return client.query(q.Create(q.Ref("classes/todos"), todoItem))
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("success", response)
    /* Success! return the response with statusCode 200 */
    return callback(null, {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(response)
    })
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("error", error)
    /* Error! return the error with statusCode 400 */
    return callback(null, {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify(error)
    })
  })
}
```

error without stringify in fetch body:

```
[BACK] [LAMBDA] Request from ::ffff:127.0.0.1: POST /todos-create
[BACK] [LAMBDA] <<<<<<<<<      [object Object]       >>>>>>>>>
[BACK] [LAMBDA] <<<<<<<<<      "[object Object]"       >>>>>>>>>
[BACK] [LAMBDA] <<<<<<<<<      [object Object]       >>>>>>>>>
[BACK] [LAMBDA] Function `todo-create` invoked [object Object]
[BACK] [LAMBDA] error { [BadRequest: validation failed]
[BACK] [LAMBDA]   name: 'BadRequest',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]   message: 'validation failed',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]   requestResult:
[BACK] [LAMBDA]    RequestResult {
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      client:
[BACK] [LAMBDA]       Client {
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         _baseUrl: 'https://db.fauna.com:443',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         _timeout: 60000,
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         _secret: '*************************',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         _observer: null,
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         _lastSeen: 1559289243066157 },
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      method: 'POST',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      path: '',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      query: null,
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      requestRaw: undefined,
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      requestContent: Expr { raw: [Object] },
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      responseRaw:
[BACK] [LAMBDA]       '{"errors":[{"position":[],"code":"validation failed","description":"Instance data is not valid.","failures":[{"field":["data"],"code":"invalid type","description":"Invalid type String, expected type Map."}]}]}',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      responseContent: { errors: [Array] },
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      statusCode: 400,
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      responseHeaders:
[BACK] [LAMBDA]       { 'content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         date: 'Fri, 31 May 2019 07:54:03 GMT',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-bus-bytes-in': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-bus-bytes-out': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-bus-messages-in': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-bus-messages-out': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-faunadb-build': '2.6.4.rc4-3fa8865',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-faunadb-host': 'ec2-35-173-239-41.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-points-network-out': '0.0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-points-storage-read': '0.0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-points-storage-write': '0.0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-points-total': '0.0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-query-bytes-in': '82',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-query-bytes-out': '209',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-query-time': '3',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-read-ops': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-storage-bytes-read': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-storage-bytes-write': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-storage-ops-delete': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-storage-ops-read': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-storage-ops-write': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-txn-delay': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-txn-retries': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-txn-time': '1559289243066157',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-write-ops': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'content-length': '209',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         connection: 'Close' },
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      startTime: 1559289242318,
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      endTime: 1559289243199 } }
[BACK] [LAMBDA] Response with status 400 in 883 ms.
[BACK] [LAMBDA] (node:5201) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at callback (/home/mathieu/Bureau/acrabadabra/Acrabadabra/node_modules/netlify-lambda/lib/serve.js:35:42)
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at /home/mathieu/Bureau/acrabadabra/Acrabadabra/node_modules/netlify-lambda/lib/serve.js:67:7
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at tryCatch (/home/mathieu/Bureau/acrabadabra/Acrabadabra/functions/todos-create.js:1803:12)
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at invokeCallback (/home/mathieu/Bureau/acrabadabra/Acrabadabra/functions/todos-create.js:1818:13)
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at publish (/home/mathieu/Bureau/acrabadabra/Acrabadabra/functions/todos-create.js:1792:7)
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at flush (/home/mathieu/Bureau/acrabadabra/Acrabadabra/functions/todos-create.js:1522:5)
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
[BACK] [LAMBDA] (node:5201) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 7)
```

error with:

```
[BACK] [LAMBDA] Request from ::ffff:127.0.0.1: POST /todos-create
[BACK] [LAMBDA] <<<<<<<<<      {"title":"What I had for breakfast ..","completed":true}       >>>>>>>>>
[BACK] [LAMBDA] <<<<<<<<<      "{\"title\":\"What I had for breakfast ..\",\"completed\":true}"       >>>>>>>>>
[BACK] [LAMBDA] <<<<<<<<<      {"title":"What I had for breakfast ..","completed":true}       >>>>>>>>>
[BACK] [LAMBDA] Function `todo-create` invoked {"title":"What I had for breakfast ..","completed":true}
[BACK] [LAMBDA] <<<<<<<<<      [object Object]       >>>>>>>>>
[BACK] [LAMBDA] (node:11199) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
[BACK] [LAMBDA] error { [BadRequest: validation failed]
[BACK] [LAMBDA]   name: 'BadRequest',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]   message: 'validation failed',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]   requestResult:
[BACK] [LAMBDA]    RequestResult {
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      client:
[BACK] [LAMBDA]       Client {
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         _baseUrl: 'https://db.fauna.com:443',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         _timeout: 60000,
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         _secret: '****************************',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         _observer: null,
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         _lastSeen: 1559294662744534 },
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      method: 'POST',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      path: '',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      query: null,
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      requestRaw: undefined,
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      requestContent: Expr { raw: [Object] },
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      responseRaw:
[BACK] [LAMBDA]       '{"errors":[{"position":[],"code":"validation failed","description":"Instance data is not valid.","failures":[{"field":["data"],"code":"invalid type","description":"Invalid type String, expected type Map."}]}]}',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      responseContent: { errors: [Array] },
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      statusCode: 400,
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      responseHeaders:
[BACK] [LAMBDA]       { 'content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         date: 'Fri, 31 May 2019 09:24:22 GMT',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-bus-bytes-in': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-bus-bytes-out': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-bus-messages-in': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-bus-messages-out': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-faunadb-build': '2.6.4.rc4-3fa8865',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-faunadb-host': 'ec2-35-173-239-41.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-points-network-out': '0.0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-points-storage-read': '0.0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-points-storage-write': '0.0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-points-total': '0.0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-query-bytes-in': '129',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-query-bytes-out': '209',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-query-time': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-read-ops': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-storage-bytes-read': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-storage-bytes-write': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-storage-ops-delete': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-storage-ops-read': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-storage-ops-write': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-txn-delay': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-txn-retries': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-txn-time': '1559294662744534',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'x-write-ops': '0',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         'content-length': '209',
[BACK] [LAMBDA]         connection: 'Close' },
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      startTime: 1559294662390,
[BACK] [LAMBDA]      endTime: 1559294663102 } }
[BACK] [LAMBDA] Response with status 400 in 762 ms.
[BACK] [LAMBDA] (node:11199) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at callback (/home/mathieu/Bureau/acrabadabra/Acrabadabra/node_modules/netlify-lambda/lib/serve.js:35:42)
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at /home/mathieu/Bureau/acrabadabra/Acrabadabra/node_modules/netlify-lambda/lib/serve.js:67:7
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at tryCatch (/home/mathieu/Bureau/acrabadabra/Acrabadabra/functions/todos-create.js:1803:12)
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at invokeCallback (/home/mathieu/Bureau/acrabadabra/Acrabadabra/functions/todos-create.js:1818:13)
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at publish (/home/mathieu/Bureau/acrabadabra/Acrabadabra/functions/todos-create.js:1792:7)
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at flush (/home/mathieu/Bureau/acrabadabra/Acrabadabra/functions/todos-create.js:1522:5)
[BACK] [LAMBDA]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
[BACK] [LAMBDA] (node:11199) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
[BACK] [LAMBDA] (node:11199) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

it works with directly (in lambda function):

```
const todoItem = {
    data: {"title":"What I had for breakfast ..","completed":true}
  }
```